# In maro party 10 for wii u is the RNG weighed aginst the lead player or is the RNG pure?

Tags: mario-party-10

Is there any information regarding the RNG in mario party 10 (Mario party mode) that indicates that it might be weighed? Since alot of the games I've played the player in the lead in early game has the tendency to fall behind in late game because of the bad rolls in RNG.

In short is the RNG weighed aginst the leading player?